# Copying files from windows to raspberry pi resulted in attribute error __aenter__

Tags: python, discord, raspberry-pi, attributeerror

Used winscp to move the entire folder, installed the requirements, updated them just in case and when I tried to run it I was met with an error that does not happen on my desktop client. What am I missing here?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "[directory]/main.py", line 37, in <module>
   asyncio.run(main())
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
  return loop.run_until_complete(main)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
  return future.result()
file "[directory]/main.py" line 33, in main
  async with bot:
AttributeError: __aenter__
```

A warning on the side bar of Thonny on my pi (using python 3.9.2):

```
Line 33 : Async context manager 'Bot' doesn't implement __aenter__ and __aexit__.
*It looks like the async context manager is used with an object that does not implement the async context management protocol. This message can't be emitted when using Python < 3.5*
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, it was a problem with my discordpy version on the pi. It was still using the old 1.7.3 package when it needed 2.0

Removing the old one and then installing the new one into the directory worked flawlessly.